Maximum number of requests users with seeded license + Premium license can do in power platform per day
We have 2 type of licenses for users inside our Office 365 for Power Platform :-

Seeded license through E1 & E3. for most users
Premium license. for managers and service accounts

now we mainly have 1 Power Apps which uses SharePoint as the data source + 50 power automate flows which run mainly using a service account.
Now I have a question as of October 2024, what is the maximum number of requests the users with seeded license + Premium license can do in power platform per 24 hours? for example back to June, i run too many flows while testing some workflows using a service account which have premium license, and i got this email from Microsoft:-

So can i conclude that the maximum number for premium user is 1/2 million requests per day? if this is true? then what is the number for users with seeded licenses?
Second question, till now we are not facing any issues with the maximum number of requests for users, but i am thinking in the future, if users with seeded licenses start to have issues due to the requests limit they can do per 24 hours,,, then what will be the best appraoch to follow? to upgrade those users to Premium or to license the Power Apps itself using per app plans ?
Thanks
